# How to access remotely MS SQL Server on linux ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu

How would I access MS SQL Server with ubuntu 14.04. I tried using freetds I failed to understand the process and It was my first time learning sqlmap. I have tried to read for several hours but in vain. Just give me a clue a way to proceed. I have the IP address of the database but I don't know how I can read it.

Comment: Have you tried connection using MySql Workbench ?

Comment: You should be more precise in what you want to achieve... Do you want to access the SQL server / Database with a programming language (which one?), or do you want to administrate and query the server (e.g. connect with a management tool or a remote connection)....

Comment: I want to administrate the server with a management tool, in fact I want to access it and migrate it to mysql with all the tables and their content without loosing anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DbVisualizer (https://www.dbvis.com) should work for you. Its cross platform, fairly easy to use and can connect to almost any kind of database. You'll need the IP address, port, username and password, just create a new connection and provide the connection details. You then can see the tables and run SQL against them (you're gonnna need to learn SQL if you don't know it).

It would help to know what you are trying to migrate. Im assuming the Ubuntu server is where the data is, but you haven't said what platform you are using or what format you are trying to get the data in. Are you just trying to clone the entire database to your local MySQL process?